# FreeBSD desktop

Tags: freebsd, desktop-environment

I don't know how to set up a desktop environment.Some explanations along with the commands to type in console after fresh installed FreeBSD would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite straightforward.  Type one of these commands

```
pkg install gnome2
pkg install x11/kde4
pkg install xfce
```

depending whether you would like to have GNOME, KDE or Xfce as your desktop environment.

For more info, [read the guide](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11-wm.html).